# How to convert string (number with prefix) to Double/Float in JS

Tags: javascript, string, double

How to convert a number with prefix into `double/float` e.g. `STA01.02`to `1.02`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex to strip the non-numbers (excluding ".") for a more flexible solution:

```
parseFloat("STA01.02".replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));
```

Comment: Or just `/[^\d.]/g` - you don't need to escape the `.` within the `[]`, and you don't need the `+`. (Although perhaps with the `+` is more efficient because it would only do a single replacement? Not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix always the same...

```
var str = "STA01.02";
var number = parseFloat(str.substring(3));
```

Comment: "A01.02" is given for substring(2) for this example. You need substring 3 for "01.02" or substring(4) for "1.02". substring(2) won't parseFloat correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assumed "STA0" is the fixed-length prefix, you can adjust the substring at the start you're getting rid of.

var myString = "STA01.02"; 
var noPrefix = myString.substring(4); // Just "1.02" 
var myNumber = parseFloat(noPrefix); 
console.log(myNumber); // Prints 1.02
```

Comment: Hi! The letter prefix are fixed but the number portion changes (e.g. STA01.02, STA11.03, STA23.11) so I need the "01.02" portion... will the parsing still work if there is a "0" before the "1.02" ?

Comment: Oh, if you only want to get rid of "STA" and not "STAn" where n is a number, then it's var noPrefix = myString.substring(3); // Just "01.02". Or, if you want to get rid of all letters, use the accepted solution.